# Formula to reflect changes made in "Sheet B, Sheet C, Sheet D on "SheetA" Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet containing the sheets "Main Navigation", "Drop Down", "Drop Down Sub Menu" and as the main sheet "All Pages".

I want to be able to see any changes made in the first 3 sheets mentioned on the main sheet which is "All Pages". I have a system that i am using to asses where the pages of the website are at in terms of development.

This is a consistent feature on all of the sheets. So the question is.. How do i reflect a change in "Main Navigation" or the others on the "All Pages" sheet? The sheet "All pages" has as described all the pages of the site listed. The other sheets only have the specific pages that come under the description. So there is NO overlap of cells, they have just been split.

An example of what i am looking for is if Cell D2 in "Main Navigation" has an "X" inside, cell D2 on the sheet All Pages should have an "X" inside, or if cell D6 in "Drop Down" has an "X" inside the cell that is relevant in the sheet "All Pages" should also have an "X"!

Sorry if that has confused anyone!

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Goto cell **D2** of **"All Pages"**, enter the following: `='Main Navigation'!D2`. That is to say, you specify a cell as usual, with the added step of prefacing it with the name of the sheet it resides on.

Comment: if cell `D2` in `Main Navigation` has `X` and cell `D2` in `Drop Down` has `Y` what should be in cell `D2` `All Pages`?

Comment: The "='Main Navigation'!D2" part works great when there is a value in the box, so thanks for that! When there is not however it displays a "0" understandably, is there a way to display a blank if there is no data in the referenced cell?

Comment: @enhzflep This seems to have done 90% of what i wanted so thanks! The other 10% i have worked out with a bit of trial and error!

Comment: @Woolnut - sounds like the perfect way to arrive at a solution to me. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to link every single cell, the most simple catch all solution is to use the change event. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

You can add a function which copies the changes to a cell onto your all pages. I guess you need some formula so the right change goes to the right cell which depends on how you want your page to look.